# Local Costmap do not update using Point Cloud data

Tags: navigation, pointcloud, global-costmap, local-costmap

We are having trouble updating local costmap when using Point cloud data. Sometime costmap reflects the obstacle, but mostly it doesn’t.

We are sharing logs, nav2_params and a sample images
[image]

[image]

Kindly need help on what wrong are we doing ?

**Nav2_params.yaml**

```
amcl:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    alpha1: 0.2
    alpha2: 0.2
    alpha3: 0.2
    alpha4: 0.2
    alpha5: 0.2
    base_frame_id: "base_footprint"
    beam_skip_distance: 0.5
    beam_skip_error_threshold: 0.9
    beam_skip_threshold: 0.3
    do_beamskip: false
    global_frame_id: "map"
    lambda_short: 0.1
    laser_likelihood_max_dist: 2.0
    laser_max_range: 100.0
    laser_min_range: -1.0
    laser_model_type: "likelihood_field"
    max_beams: 60
    max_particles: 2000
    min_particles: 500
    odom_frame_id: "odom"
    pf_err: 0.05
    pf_z: 0.99
    recovery_alpha_fast: 0.0
    recovery_alpha_slow: 0.0
    resample_interval: 1
    robot_model_type: "differential"
    save_pose_rate: 0.5
    sigma_hit: 0.2
    tf_broadcast: true
    transform_tolerance: 1.0
    update_min_a: 0.2
    update_min_d: 0.25
    z_hit: 0.5
    z_max: 0.05
    z_rand: 0.5
    z_short: 0.05
    scan_topic: scan
amcl_map_client:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
amcl_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
bt_navigator:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    global_frame: map
    robot_base_frame: base_link
    odom_topic: /odom
    bt_loop_duration: 10
    default_server_timeout: 20
    enable_groot_monitoring: True
    groot_zmq_publisher_port: 1666
    groot_zmq_server_port: 1667
    # 'default_nav_through_poses_bt_xml' and 'default_nav_to_pose_bt_xml' are use defaults:
    # nav2_bt_navigator/navigate_to_pose_w_replanning_and_recovery.xml
    # nav2_bt_navigator/navigate_through_poses_w_replanning_and_recovery.xml
    # They can be set here or via a RewrittenYaml remap from a parent launch file to Nav2.
    plugin_lib_names:
    - nav2_compute_path_to_pose_action_bt_node
    - nav2_compute_path_through_poses_action_bt_node
    - nav2_follow_path_action_bt_node
    - nav2_back_up_action_bt_node
    - nav2_spin_action_bt_node
    - nav2_wait_action_bt_node
    - nav2_clear_costmap_service_bt_node
    - nav2_is_stuck_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_goal_reached_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_goal_updated_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_initial_pose_received_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_reinitialize_global_localization_service_bt_node
    - nav2_rate_controller_bt_node
    - nav2_distance_controller_bt_node
    - nav2_speed_controller_bt_node
    - nav2_truncate_path_action_bt_node
    - nav2_goal_updater_node_bt_node
    - nav2_recovery_node_bt_node
    - nav2_pipeline_sequence_bt_node
    - nav2_round_robin_node_bt_node
    - nav2_transform_available_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_time_expired_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_distance_traveled_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_single_trigger_bt_node
    - nav2_is_battery_low_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_navigate_through_poses_action_bt_node
    - nav2_navigate_to_pose_action_bt_node
    - nav2_remove_passed_goals_action_bt_node
    - nav2_planner_selector_bt_node
    - nav2_controller_selector_bt_node
    - nav2_goal_checker_selector_bt_node
bt_navigator_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
controller_server:
  ros__parameters:
    # controller server parameters (see Controller Server for more info)
    use_sim_time: False
    controller_frequency: 20.0
    min_x_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    min_y_velocity_threshold: 0.5
    min_theta_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    progress_checker_plugin: "progress_checker"
    goal_checker_plugins: ["goal_checker"]
    controller_plugins: ["FollowPath"]
    progress_checker:
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleProgressChecker"
      required_movement_radius: 0.5
      movement_time_allowance: 10.0
    goal_checker:
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleGoalChecker"
      xy_goal_tolerance: 0.25
      yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.25
      xy_goal_tolerance: 0.3
      yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.3
      stateful: True
    # DWB controller parameters
    FollowPath:

      plugin: "dwb_core::DWBLocalPlanner"
      debug_trajectory_details: True
      min_vel_x: 0.0
      min_vel_y: 0.0
      max_vel_x: 0.25
      max_vel_y: 0.0
      max_vel_theta: 0.4
      min_speed_xy: 0.0
      max_speed_xy: 0.25
      min_speed_theta: 0.0
      acc_lim_x: 2.5
      acc_lim_y: 0.0
      acc_lim_theta: 2.5
      decel_lim_x: -2.5
      decel_lim_y: 0.0
      decel_lim_theta: -2.5
      vx_samples: 20
      vy_samples: 5
      vtheta_samples: 20
      sim_time: 1.7
      linear_granularity: 0.05
      angular_granularity: 0.025
      transform_tolerance: 0.2
      xy_goal_tolerance: 0.15
      trans_stopped_velocity: 0.25
      short_circuit_trajectory_evaluation: True
      stateful: True
      critics: ["RotateToGoal", "Oscillation", "BaseObstacle", "GoalAlign", "PathAlign", "PathDist", "GoalDist"]
      BaseObstacle.scale: 0.02
      PathAlign.scale: 32.0
      GoalAlign.scale: 24.0
      PathAlign.forward_point_distance: 0.1
      GoalAlign.forward_point_distance: 0.1
      PathDist.scale: 32.0
      GoalDist.scale: 24.0
      RotateToGoal.scale: 32.0
      RotateToGoal.slowing_factor: 5.0
      RotateToGoal.lookahead_time: -1.0
 
 
controller_server_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
local_costmap:
  local_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      update_frequency: 5.0
      publish_frequency: 2.0
      global_frame: map
      robot_base_frame: base_link
      use_sim_time: false
      rolling_window: true
      width: 5
      height: 5
      resolution: 0.05
      #robot_radius: 0.5
      footprint: "[[0.30, 0.22], [0.30, -0.22], [-0.30, -0.22], [-0.30, 0.22]]"
      plugins: ["obstacle_layer", "inflation_layer"]
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        cost_scaling_factor: 3.0
        inflation_radius: 0.6
      obstacle_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
        enabled: True
        observation_sources: pointcloud
        pointcloud:
          topic: /cloud_filter
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          min_obstacle_height: 0.0
          raytrace_max_range: 3.0
          raytrace_min_range: 0.0
          obstacle_max_range: 3.0
          obstacle_min_range: 0.0
          inf_is_valid: True
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "PointCloud2"
      voxel_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::VoxelLayer"
        enabled: True
        publish_voxel_map: True
        origin_z: 0.0
        z_resolution: 0.05
        z_voxels: 16
        max_obstacle_height: 2.0
        mark_threshold: 0
        observation_sources: pointcloud
        pointcloud:
          topic: /cloud
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "PointCloud2"
          raytrace_max_range: 3.0
          raytrace_min_range: 0.03
          obstacle_max_range: 2.5
          obstacle_min_range: 0.03
      static_layer:
        map_subscribe_transient_local: True
      always_send_full_costmap: True
  local_costmap_client:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: False
  local_costmap_rclcpp_node:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: False
global_costmap:
  global_costmap:
    ros__parameters:     
      update_frequency: 1.0
      publish_frequency: 1.0
      global_frame: map
      robot_base_frame: base_link
      use_sim_time: False
      #robot_radius: 0.5
      footprint: "[[0.30, 0.22], [0.30, -0.22], [-0.30, -0.22], [-0.30, 0.22]]"
      resolution: 0.05
      track_unknown_space: true
      plugins: ["static_layer", "obstacle_layer", "inflation_layer"]
      obstacle_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
        enabled: True
        observation_sources: pointcloud
        pointcloud:
          topic: /cloud_filter
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "PointCloud2"
          raytrace_max_range: 3.0
          raytrace_min_range: 0.0
          obstacle_max_range: 3.0
          obstacle_min_range: 0.0
          obstacle_max_range: 3.0
          obstacle_min_range: 0.0
 
      static_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::StaticLayer"
        map_subscribe_transient_local: True
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        cost_scaling_factor: 3.0
        inflation_radius: 0.6
      always_send_full_costmap: True
  global_costmap_client:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: False
  global_costmap_rclcpp_node:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: False
map_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    yaml_filename: "fae_map.yaml"
map_saver:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    save_map_timeout: 5.0
    free_thresh_default: 0.25
    occupied_thresh_default: 0.65
    map_subscribe_transient_local: True
planner_server:
  ros__parameters:
    expected_planner_frequency: 15.0
    use_sim_time: False
    planner_plugins: ["GridBased"]
    GridBased:
      plugin: "nav2_navfn_planner/NavfnPlanner"
      tolerance: 0.5
      use_astar: false
      allow_unknown: true
planner_server_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
recoveries_server:
  ros__parameters:
    costmap_topic: local_costmap/costmap_raw
    footprint_topic: local_costmap/published_footprint
    cycle_frequency: 10.0
    recovery_plugins: ["spin", "backup", "wait"]
    spin:
      plugin: "nav2_recoveries/Spin"
    backup:
      plugin: "nav2_recoveries/BackUp"
    wait:
      plugin: "nav2_recoveries/Wait"
    global_frame: odom
    robot_base_frame: base_link
    transform_timeout: 0.1
    use_sim_time: False
    simulate_ahead_time: 2.0
    max_rotational_vel: 0.8
    min_rotational_vel: 0.2
    rotational_acc_lim: 3.2
robot_state_publisher:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: false
waypoint_follower:
  ros__parameters:
    loop_rate: 20
    stop_on_failure: false
    waypoint_task_executor_plugin: "wait_at_waypoint"   
    wait_at_waypoint:
      plugin: "nav2_waypoint_follower::WaitAtWaypoint"
      enabled: True
      waypoint_pause_duration: 200
```

Comment: Receiving logs like this
 
    [adiroboticskit.py-2] [controller_server-1] [WARN] [1710240194.833658488] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Sensor origin at (2.74, 0.03) is out of map bounds (-0.4 0, -1.4 0) to (2.58, 1.57). The costmap cannot raytrace for it.

Answer (score 0):

Increase ray_trace_max_range and obstacle_max_range to values > 3.0 meters. This default is only for tutorial purposes. If in your urdf the lidar is set to "see" 100 meters for example and in local/global costmap it can see just 3 meters, the scan will spread to unknown area ( meaning of the message "Sensor is out of map bounds).

Probably you will also need to modify something similar to mapping range on mapper_params_online_sync.yaml on params or conf folder in you are relying on Slam-toolbox (located on opt/Ros/distro/share/slam-toolbox/params)

Comment: Does it also implies for Depth sensor giving PointCloud data which has range upto 2 meter ?

We are using cartographer for SLAM. any suggestion to tweak cartographer parameter ?

Comment: What is your suggestion, if my depth data giving point cloud upto 1.3 meters ? Shall we keep raytrace_max_range and obstacle_max_range greater than 1.3 or less than 1.3 ?